# Why am I frequently getting this “Cannot allocate memory” error?

Tags: r

I am trying solve a problem to make a crosstable from a data frame consists of two  variables ( article ID and user ID) I am trying to make a cross table from a data frame. that cross table will be sued to find the degree centrality of users and articles. i have the data-frame  like

```
article  user

  1        u1
  1        u2
  1        u3
  2        u2
  2        u4
  2        u5
  3        u1
  3        u6
  3        u4
  3        u7
```

this just an example I have dataframe of dimension

```
dim(x)   
[1] 364323      2
```

when I apply the code to a dataframe it gives me an error like

```
n<-(table(y)>0)*1 ##Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.4 Gb
```

same with the cross table

```
article   users

         u1  u2  u3  u4 u5 u6 u7
 1        1   1   1   0  0  0  0
 2        0   1   0   1  1  0  0
 3        1   0   0   1  0  1  1
```

with additional warnings

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 12.9 Gb

In addition: Warning messages:

1: In matrix(0L, nc = n.u, nr = n.u) :

  Reached total allocation of 4078Mb: see help(memory.size)

2: In matrix(0L, nc = n.u, nr = n.u) :
  Reached total allocation of 4078Mb: see help(memory.size)

3: In matrix(0L, nc = n.u, nr = n.u) :

  Reached total allocation of 4078Mb: see help(memory.size)


4: In matrix(0L, nc = n.u, nr = n.u) :

  Reached total allocation of 4078Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

any help will highly be appreciated

Comment: Well, you can easily calculate how big the table is going to be. If you have many articles and many users, it's to big for your memory.

Comment: @Roland how can i overcome this problem?

Comment: How much RAM do you have on your OS and what `memory.limit()` tells you?

Comment: Buy more RAM? Seriously, you don't even tell us what you are trying to achieve. That makes it difficult to suggest alternatives.

Comment: @Roland, it may be solved by increasing `memory.limit()`. Maybe he already has enough RAM

Comment: @DavidArenburg Possibly, maybe. In my experience that usually doesn't help. Instead it's often better to focus on better algorithms. I doubt that they need to calculate `table(x)`.

Comment: @Roland I am trying to find the centrality of user from the crosstable  but by applying the commands it gives me that errors

Comment: @DavidArenburg I have a ram of size 4 gb and memory.limit tells me 4078

Comment: I second @Roland, buy more RAM